# Does LinkedIn sometimes require sign-in to view profiles?

Tags: linkedin

For a few weeks, LinkedIn has been requiring me to sign in before I'm allowed to view profiles, including my own. I know it's not simply an invitation to join LinkedIn because:

1. There is no "skip" option
2. Simply leaving the login form blank results in an error saying my credentials are incorrect
3. This happens *even when I'm already signed in* (although it only seems to occur when I follow links to profiles from a search engine)

This is very strange, because it only happens when I access LinkedIn through certain computers.

As far as I'm aware, basic profile information is supposed to be public.

Is this something that was recently changed?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this happen.

If I try to access any profile page from my mobile phone, all I get is a sign-up form claiming that I should sign up to see "full profiles", though **none** of the profile is visible.

If I use a computer however, some details are visible.

The conclusion is that LinkedIn **does** shadily censor your account from some users (even if you set it as public).

It has become worse that it was, and worse than a plain webpage, by holding my account hostage, and blackmailing users to sign up in order to see it.
This led me personally to lose trust in the service, and to stop using it.

An article that influenced me is this one, from Richard Stallman himself:

[Richard Stallman on LinkedIn](https://stallman.org/linkedin.html)

Here is a screenshot from my mobile device, hiding a "public" account entirely:

[image: Sign-up form covering whole mobile page]